# How to scrape promtail based on date

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I'm trying to scrape logs from a service which publishes its logs on a URL:

https://example.com/logs/logs.json?date=2023-09-09

Is there a good way to set up scrape configs for this in promtail (struggling to find any documentation) or do we need to look at some sort of push-based solution instead (or something other than promtail?)

Comment: AFAIK, promtail cannot scrape logs from dynamic targets like this.  If this is your own developed service, and you are free to integrate loki client to it, to push logs without promtail - this is probably a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, suspected as much. Not our own service, unfortunately, but we do host the service (and can thus also access the log files if we need to), so I guess we'll figure something out.